# jquery colorbox bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have search all over for 3 Days and cannot find the answer
I try to remove the **grey area** in the bottom of the **COLORBOX Popup** where the close button position but I cannot find the way to do it. I try add remove navigation and its still there in the bottom of the **POPUP** I have the area in gray colour

I use this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       // $.fn.colorbox({scrolling:false, overlayClose:false, opacity:0.7, escKey:false, href:"#subscribe", 'open':true, 'inline':true, 'width':'auto', 'height':'auto'});
        //$('#cboxClose').remove();
          $.fn.colorbox({scrolling:false, overlayClose:false, opacity:0.7, escKey:false, href:"#subscribe", 'open':true, 'inline':true, 'width':'auto', 'height':'auto'});
          $('#cboxClose').remove();

        }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#cboxLoadedContent{} //remove the margin-bottom:20px;
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a demo site that I can look at? I've removed the close button from colorbox in a site I'm working on (using the same $('#cboxClose').remove() jQuery snippet as you) and there's no grey area besides the normal shaded border around the colorbox content.

[EDIT]
Ah! @Sudhir's answer prompted me to examine your code more closely - you haven't passed the .remove() code in as the onLoad function, so there may be no close button to remove when that line runs - it might not have been created yet!

Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to add a comment to @sudhir's correct answer so I'll have to put it here instead.

The important part of @Sudhir's answer is the

```
onLoad: function(){
    $('#cboxClose').remove()
}
```

part. This will only run after the colorbox has fully loaded, at which point you should have a close button to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about anyone else, but just removing the close button (which you can do with "closeButton: false" parameter/value in the colorbox constructor) didn't work for me. I was trying to get rid of the grey/silver rectangular box (controls container) running along the bottom of the colorbox. The close button gets removed, but the grey container area remains.

In the end, I had to create 2 new png images (for the left and right sides of the border), modify one existing png image (colorbox-border.png) and modify 3 lines in the colorbox CSS file. So, here's what you need:

Save these 3 pngs and add them to your images directory (or wherever):

[image: colorbox-border-bottom-left.png] **<<** colorbox-border-bottom-left.png

[image: colorbox-border-bottom-middle.png] **<<** colorbox-border-bottom-middle.png (There is an image there! It's only 1x9 px)

[image: colorbox-border-bottom-right.png] **<<** colorbox-border-bottom-right.png

You'll also need to update the colorbox CSS file. Replace these 3 lines:

```
#cboxBottomLeft{width:14px; height:43px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;}
#cboxBottomCenter{height:43px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-border.png) repeat-x bottom left;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:14px; height:43px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-controls.png) no-repeat -36px -32px;}
```

...with these 3 lines:

```
#cboxBottomLeft{width:14px; height:9px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-border-bottom-left.png) no-repeat}
#cboxBottomCenter{width:1px; height:9px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-border-bottom-middle.png) repeat-x bottom left;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:14px; height:9px; background:url([WHEREVER_UR_IMAGES_ARE]/colorbox-border-bottom-right.png) no-repeat}
```

Don't forget to change the name of the pngs in the CSS file if you don't save them using those names e.g. colorbox-border-bottom-....

Here's an example of the result:

[image]